# vtk - Reset volume property

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, vtk

I have an volume with some properties, for instance:

```
    m_pVolumeProperty->SetScalarOpacity(m_pVolumeScalarOpacity);
    m_pVolumeScalarOpacity->AddPoint(0.0, 0.0);
    m_pVolumeScalarOpacity->AddPoint(1.0, 0.1);

    m_pVolume->SetMapper(m_pVolumeMapper);
    m_pVolume->SetProperty(m_pVolumeProperty);

    m_pRenderer->AddActor(m_pVolume);
    m_pRenderer->ResetCamera();

    m_pRenderWindow->Start();
    m_pRenderer->Render();
    m_pRenderWindow->Render();
```

but at runtime, I want to change these values (scalar opacity) without to close the window ... is this posible ? If yes, how can achieve that ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your values in m_pVolumeScalarOpacity, update the volume and re-render

```
m_pVolumeScalarOpacity->AddPoint(0.8, 0.8);
m_pVolume->Update();
m_pRenderWindow->Render();
```

If you like to use m_pVolumeScalarOpacity for different views, like bone, skin etc.,
then you should clear the instance before you add the points.

e.g.

```
m_pVolumeScalarOpacity->RemoveAllPoints();
```

Comment: Johnny, is working now !!! :) I am sorry that I can not vote you because I don't have enough reputation ... but please take my thanks !